# How to use Redux state in function?

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a function that I keep in a separate file for clarity and I try to make a Redux Action and also get the state from it. I call this function this inside my App.js that is connected to the Provider, but it says props.jwt is undefined. I tried to connect and export it as a Component, but did not work.

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getCurrentUserInformation} from '../actions/actions';
import instance from '../config/instance';

function getUserInformation(props) {
  instance
    .get('/api/user_information/', {
      headers: {Authorization: 'Token ' + props.jwt},
    })
    .then(response => {
      props.getCurrentUserInformation(
        response.data.id,
        response.data.username,
        response.data.profile_image,
        response.data.followers,
        response.data.following,
      );
    })
    .catch(error => {});
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    currentUser: state.userReducer.currentUser,
    jwt: state.userReducer.jwt,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getCurrentUserInformation: (
      id,
      username,
      profileImage,
      followers,
      following,
    ) =>
      dispatch(
        getCurrentUserInformation(
          id,
          username,
          profileImage,
          followers,
          following,
        ),
      ),
  };
}
```

Comment: Are you running it through connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Redux Hooks. Instead of mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps you can use useSelector and useDispatch to get access to your state in the function. You can find more in the official documentation here: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks

Comment: I tried it and the problem is that I call it inside useEffect so I get an error for not calling it in a function body.

Comment: Actually I could make some improvements with your answer and also it is less code so thank you so much!